# Is there a tool like DOM inspector for flash swf?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

So that I can know which part of mxml the border color is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several Flash/Flex consoles out there.

I don't know all of them but [KapInspect](http://lab.kapit.fr/display/kapinspect/Kap+Inspect) does a great job for that.